# How could I call a function after the function that loads the layers ends up loading the layers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgis

I'm using pyqt5 to make a Qgis 3.4 plugin, this plugin is supposed to load  pair o layers and zoom to the selected one, but the code executes too fast and passes the zooming line before the layers are loaded into Qgis.

the code is the following:

```
def openFileNameDialog(self):

    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Shapefile's (*.shp)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        shape_name = fileName

    shapelayer = QgsVectorLayer(shape_name, "project's shapefile", "ogr")
    if not shapelayer:
      self.statusBar().showMessage('shapefile is invalid')

    else:


        urlWithParams = 'url=urltoBaseMap'

        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'BaseMap', 'wms')

        if not rlayer.isValid():
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Layer failed to load!')

        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shapelayer)

        self.iface.setActiveLayer(shapelayer)

def layerzoom(self):

    self.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()

def runboth(self):

    self.openFileNameDialog()
    #time.sleep(5)
    self.layerzoom()
```

how could I call a function to zoom after the function that loads the layers finishes the layers' loading?

I've tried time.sleep() but it doesn't wait for openFileNameFialog() to finish so the problem presist.

Comment: the problem is not as generic as your title indicates, the solution depends on qgis, for example, check if qgis emits a signal that indicates that the resource has been fully loaded, and that signal is connected to a slot that zooms.

Comment: (not expert in qgis) try with `drawingProgress` signal

Comment: Maybe I am not asking correctly, my real question is how to chain a function after another one has been called without having to call it inside the first function in this case `openFileNameDialog()` and avoid using `runboth` That's why the title was written the way it was before the edit.

Comment: @eyllanesc drawingProgress cannot be used in this version.

Comment: @Thriskel There are operations in `openFileNameDialog()` that execute asynchronously, so there is no way for the caller to know when it will complete. That is why signals and/or events are required in cases like this. Chaining the calls will not solve the problem at all.

Comment: The nice way would be using the signals of QgsProject, e. g. https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Project/QgsProject.html#qgis.core.QgsProject.layersAdded

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ekhumoro, the problem was solved by declaring **stop_signal** inside openFileNameDialog().

This **stop_signal** contains what is going to be called **after the layer loads**.

Then the signal has to be sent to the stop_signal function after the render is completed by declaring it **at the end** of the openFileNameDialog function.

Code should be something like this:

```
def openFileNameDialog(self):
    
    """
    Code...
    """

    def stop_signal():  
        self.layeropen()

    """
    Code loading layers and whatever needed..
    """

    self.iface.mapCanvas().renderComplete.connect(stop_signal)
```